# how to create Localized base Application for android

Tags: android

So I just started learning android but i would like to built a localized base application for android. Is there any tutorials in the web or videos perhaps I can learn from? I have watched all the basic android videos now I feel it is the right time to build this app of mine but I would really appreciate it if anyone can give me direction to go ?

Any advice or pointers is very much appreciated! Thanks

PS:

BY LOCALIZED BASE APP i meant I want to the app to work like this:
How about if I want my app to work with every users being able to see which other users are around his proximity? What resources should I look into?

Comment: go thru this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: you know what does the base app mean ? According to my understanding base apps are those which comes pre installed like COntacts , Calendar , Settings etc

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the [the official developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html). Basically, you want to use qualifiers. For example, if you want to localize your app in english and hungarian, you want to have 3 folders in your res folder, like this:

- values    //default values, if the device locale is neither english, nor hungarian, this is loaded
- values-en //if the device locale is english, this gets loaded
- values-hu //if the device locale is hungarian, this gets loaded

Of course, you can force the locale inside your application, but that is another matter, for starting, this is fair enough I think.

Comment: How about if I want my app to work with every users being able to see which user is around his proximity? What resources should I look into?

Comment: I don't really understand what do you mean, if you could explain it further, that'd be good.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/android-application-localization-tutorial/) You've got step by step tutorial.

You should use `strings.xml` with different translations in different /res/values* folders.

EDIT:

For general study my fav [vogella.com tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/android.html).